# Getting distinct unordered tuples from a collection: where is the flaw in my code?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, oop

It's pretty self-explanatory what I'm trying to do.

**My code:**

```
public class Solution
{       
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> t1 = Tuple.Create(1,2);
        Tuple<int, int> t2 = Tuple.Create(1,2);
        Tuple<int, int> t3 = Tuple.Create(2,1);
        List<Tuple<int, int>> tups = new List<Tuple<int, int>>() { t1, t2, t3 };
        var dist = tups.Distinct(new TupleComparer());
        foreach(var t in dist)
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", t.Item1, t.Item2);
    }
}


class TupleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<int,int> a, Tuple<int, int> b)
    {
        return a.Item1 == b.Item1 && a.Item2 == b.Item2
            || a.Item1 == b.Item2 && a.Item2 == b.Item1 ;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<int, int> t)
    {
        return t.Item1 + 31 * t.Item2;
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
1,2
```

(or `2,1`)

**Actual output:**

```
1,2
2,1
```

Where is the flaw?

Hopefully, typing this line will make my text-to-code ratio high enough to submit the question.

Comment: Did you try parentheses? `(a.Item1 == b.Item1 && a.Item2 == b.Item2) || (a.Item1 == b.Item2 && a.Item2 == b.Item1)`

Answer (score 3):

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
// then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
```

That is not the case in your implementation.

for tuple (1,2), GetHashcode produces 63

for tuple (2,1) this would be 33.

Distinct() utilizes GetHashCode, not Equals.

Order matters in your implementation.

The Equals implementation does not take this in account, as the order does not matter there.

So the results are indeed distinct from the HashCode´s point of view ;)